# Basic question about cross validation

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation

A very basic question about cross validation for Neural Networks.

Do I have to create a new network for each fold or do I have to keep the network and incrementally train it with the k-th training set?

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part3/section-12.html says "You train the net k-times..." which let's me assume to use the same net every fold again. But when I don't create a new network for each fold, then I would use the k-th fold k-1 times.

In [this picture](http://genome.tugraz.at/proclassify/help/pages/XV.html) you see that without a new network, e.g. the first 4 data points would be used to train the model in the 2nd to 5th step.

Can you give me a hint on the right interpretation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each fold, a new model should be completely developed on a training set. Then the samples in the separate test should be classified to determine the error rate. The samples in the test set should **not** be used for **any** aspect of model development. This includes variable selection, selection of cutpoints, etc. I haven't worked with neural networks before but I assume this advice also holds true for them. If you are doing ten-fold cross-validation, you should make ten different, totally independent models.

See this paper by Refaeilzadeh, et al., for an accessible overview:

- http://leitang.net/papers/ency-cross-validation.pdf